# Increment code coverage on Android by ignoring methods with Context, View

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, jacoco

I'm trying to increment the code coverage with JaCoCo on my Android project and I found I could ignore entire classes with/without regex.

I'm following an MVP pattern, so first of all I'm ignoring all `**/view/**`

But then I have, for example, **helpers** that have methods like:

```
companion object {
    fun fromHtml(html: String): Spanned {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            Html.fromHtml(html)
        }
    }

    fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
        try {
            val inputManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.currentFocus!!.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.w(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I can test `fromHtml` with JUnit, but to test `hideKeyboard(Activity)` I need an `Activity`, or better said, run it through an **instrumented test**.

Is there any way I can generate JaCoCo reports ignoring methods that contain `View`, `Activity`, `Context`, etc in their signature?